# Entity Framework Core concurrency token opt-out under specific circumstances

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In this scenario we have a hypothetical order management system which is used to track customers' fast food orders from various restaurants (imagine an extremely simplified UberEats backend system). This system is administered by multiple staff.

`Pending` orders must be manually moved into a `Processing` or `Flagged for Review` status by a staff member. Depending on which status the order is moved in to, a different email will queued in a `QueuedEmail` table to be sent to the customer.

Because the system is being used by multiple staff, there is always the chance of race conditions. For example, two staff members simultaneously changing an order's status to `Processing` and `Flagged for Review` respectively.

With no concurrency controls in place, this would result in the customer receiving two emails with messages which contradict eachother. We cannot have that.

So we take the optimistic concurrency control route, and add a `StatusChangedUtc` column to our `Order` table and tell EF Core to treat it as a Concurrency Token.

Great, now there is no way for two simultaneous updates to leave the database in an inconsistent state.

BUT, where one problem is solved, another is created.

You see, in our hypothetical order management system, we also periodically poll restaurants for ETAs (the approximate time delivery is expected to take once the order is released for processing).

This is done in a background task, and we save this ETA against the `Order` in an `DeliveryEta` column. This background task is aggressive, updating orders frequently.

Here's the problem.. Because of the concurrency token we introduced, the background task now encounters concurrency exceptions when staff members are simultaneously updating the orders.

But this should not be the case, because the `DeliveryEta` is purely for informational/display purposes, and it has no effect on the actions a staff member can perform.

The background task should be free to update `DeliveryEta` when it wants, as often as it wants, and for it to never encounter a concurrency exception.

So.....

How on earth do I tell EfCore to ignore the concurrency token in specific circumstances?

And actually, it kind of seems to me like EfCore's concurrent token feature is poorly designed. Why should the concurrency token be checked with every single database update? Wouldn't it be better if the concurrency token was only checked when the value of the concurrency token is changing?

This way, I could opt-in in to concurrency token checking just by changing the token. Seems like a more fine grained solution, no?

Comment: Concurrency columns are supposed to be used for all updates to that record. You could consider splitting the user maintained columns and the batch job columns into separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I rolled my own solution which allows me to opt-in, rather than having the concurrency check performed with every update.

To achieve this, I override the `SaveChanges` method on the `DbContext`. Here I look for any `Order` where the `StatusUpdatedUtc` has changed, and execute a manual SQL query which performs an update, and checks the number of rows affected.

Note that because the database update is in a separate query, it's important that any updates to `Order` which affect `StatusUpdatedUtc` be executed inside a transaction.

Here's my code:

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{

    foreach (var orderEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Order>())
    {

        if (orderEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {

            var statusUpdatedProperty = orderEntry.Property(j => j.StatusUpdatedUtc);

            if (statusUpdatedProperty.IsModified)
            {

                var updatedRows = await Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(@"
                    UPDATE [Orders]
                    SET [Orders].[StatusUpdatedUtc] = @p2
                    WHERE [Orders].[Id] = @p0
                    AND [Orders].[StatusUpdatedUtc] = @p1;",
                    new object[]
                    {
                    orderEntry.Entity.Id,
                    statusUpdatedProperty.OriginalValue,
                    statusUpdatedProperty.CurrentValue,
                    },
                    cancellationToken);

                if (updatedRows == 0)
                {
                    throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException("Update prevented by order concurrency protection");
                }

            }

        }

    }

    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options to consider:

1. Implement a retry in your background task. If it encounters an issue, reload the order and try the update again.
2. More of a future consideration: Designing the schema in a way that it is *not* dependent on a single table row for unrelated operations. For instance rather than having a "DeliveryETA" on an order row. An order will likely have other information relevant to a Delivery, such as a delivery address, notes, etc. which would include an ETA. It's a One-to-ZeroOrOne relationship with an order, so an OrderDelivery entity. The background job would create or update the OrderDelivery which would be isolated from updates to the Order. The concurrency check/handling would, and should only apply if any system touches the Delivery-related details.

Concurrency checks are a good thing, and they should be caught and handled. That handling in a User front end might be simply bringing up a message asking them to try again and reloading the page; or it might need to involve an automatic retry attempt. It's generally not something that you'd want to create a back door to ignore in one scenario, because that "hack" tends to get noticed and justified to be used far more frequently.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but doing retries in a background task seemed unnecessarily dirty, and I feel the solution I came up with is better, given that a refactoring of the schema wasn't really a good use of my time.